# Displaying CGRect position reset my image position

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm making some [CGRect Utils](https://github.com/martin-magakian/CGRect-Utils) class and function to help us manipulating CGRect and View's frame.


I'm facing a very strange problem. I have an image, that I can move by pressing some button.

```
- (IBAction)heightPlusTen:(id)sender {
    CGRectAddHeightToView(myView, 10);
}
```

CGRectAddHeightToView is just a #define and it can be replace by:

```
- (IBAction)heightPlusTen:(id)sender {
    myView.frame = CGRectMake( myView.frame.origin.x,
             myView.frame.origin.y,
             myView.frame.size.width,
             myView.frame.size.height+10 );
}
```

So far the image is moving. Everything looks fine...
Until I run this code:

```
- (IBAction)updatePosition:(id)sender {
    xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", duck.frame.origin.x];
    yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", duck.frame.origin.y];
    wLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", duck.frame.size.width];
    hLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", duck.frame.size.height];
}
```

It's suppose to display the x,y,width and height on the screen. But instead it move back the image to it **almost** initial position.

I know lot of code is missing so checkout [CGRect Utils on github](https://github.com/martin-magakian/CGRect-Utils).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should consider using ARC in this day and age.

As for your question: `autolayout` is causing this frame reset when you update the labels.

If you disable it on `ViewController.xib` then your code works "as expected".

A very good tutorial on autolayout and how to use it can be found here: [Beginning Auto Layout in iOS 6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

`Autolayout` is a great tool but can sometimes cause serious headaches.

Answer (score 2):

It's autolayout that's causing the problem.. Now you can just delete auto-layout all together, or you can keep it (along with its many benefits) but also insantiate the labels as soon as the xib loads.. like so:

```
// ViewController.m 
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", duck.frame.origin.x];
    yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", duck.frame.origin.y];
    wLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", duck.frame.size.width];
    hLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", duck.frame.size.height];        
}
```

that way autolayout won't have to readjust anything when you update the labels in the future.